# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory (although file exists)

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, path, text-to-speech, librosa

```
def extract_features(file_path):
    sr, y = wavfile.read(file_path)
    mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=40) 
    return mfccs

features = []
labels = []

for i, row in data.iterrows(): 
    file_path = os.path.join(data_dir, row[0])
    repr(file_path)
    transcription = row[1]
    feature = extract_features(file_path) 
    features.append(feature) 
    labels.append(transcription)
```

The above code throws the following error:

```
File "c:\Users\Adyatoni\OneDrive\Desktop\PROGRAMS\Beng tts 2", line 31, in <module>
    feature = extract_features(file_path) #The resulting feature matrix is stored in the feature variable.
  File "c:\Users\Adyatoni\OneDrive\Desktop\PROGRAMS\Beng tts 2", line 19, in extract_features
    sr, y = wavfile.read(file_path)
  File "C:\Users\Adyatoni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 647, in read
    fid = open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Adyatoni\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\PROGRAMS\\Bengali tts audio\\ bin_0834_0030520634.wav'
```

The file exists in the location but for some reason, python cannot recognize it.

I have tried printing the file_path and it shows the same path as shown in the error. I have tried using librosa instead of wavfile to extract the features. However, the audio path does work for other programs.
I'm still new in this field and thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to substitute/delete the spaces for naming the directory (and the file somehow looks like there is a space in front as well)? Spaces are not very handy when it comes to programming. Try using underscores for example.

Comment: @Baradrist Thank you so much pointing that out. It works fine now...